# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer CORS Error in angular and ASP.Net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am trying to view pdf file using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer in angular with ASP.net Core as backend. This is my template:

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="pdfsrc" 
                        [height]="'95%'"
                        useBrowserLocale="true"
                        [textLayer]="true"
                        [showHandToolButton]="true"
                        >
                    </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

in my component.ts

```
 pdfsrc: any;
this.pdfsrc = this.children.studyPath;
       this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfsrc)
```

CORS policy in ASP.Net Core

```
     app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

I am getting this error Access to fetch at

`'https://localhost:5001/ChildStudyReportFolder/7a6c78dd-aa3a-46db-bbea-37a456784d1a.pdf' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that  app.UseStaticFiles();
was placed before use app.UseCors() in the startup.cs;

After placing app.UseStaticFiles() after app.UseCors();
I cleared all cache data and it works. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It may help if you could show more details,
Enable CORS in ASP.NET Core,you should set as below :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ........
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              policy =>
                              {
                                  policy.WithOrigins("......");
                              });
        });
        ......
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        ......
        app.UseRouting();
        ......

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        ......

        app.UseAuthorization();

        ......
    }
```

notice the order of the middleware,`app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);`should behind `app.UseRouting();`and before`app.UseAuthentication();`

add `[EnableCors]` on your controller

The offcial document related:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I am able to fetch data from the backend by angular, meaning the CORS is working, it is only fetching the pdf that I am having the COR issue